# How handle boundary condition on buffer size when reading synchronously from a socket?

Tags: java, android

If you call `read()` on an `InputStream` retrieved from a `Socket` (with an infinite read timeout) passing a buffer of `N` bytes and it returns `N`, how do you distinguish between these 2 cases:

1. There was exactly `N` bytes received by the socket so far and your buffer happens to have the same size

   - Calling `read()` again will block
   - You don't want that, since now you won't be able to process the received data so far until new data has been received
2. There was more than `N` bytes received by the socket so far and your buffer is too small

   - Call `read()` again should not block and just return the extra data
   - This is what you want as you will have all the received data and can process it

The first solution I can think of is to make sure `N` is greater than the internal `Socket` receive buffers, but I don't know what the value should be, and that seems very fragile.

Another possibility would be to temporarily change the read timeout of the socket to a very short one (like a few ms) for the 2nd `read()` call, so that if we're in case 1), it doesn't *really* block. That sounds like a hack though.

Comment: Have you looked at using `available()`? That is the typical way to peek at the socket to see if there is some data available before doing a `read()` which might block.

Comment: I've seen such methods in various OSes but guarantees on when they return true vs false can be all over the place. Can we assume that in Java / Android, `available()` is guaranteed to return true in this case? If so that would be the cleanest. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.